# Most simple use of Eclipse with BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, egit

I created a simple java project in Eclipse and want to use BitBucket for vcs. I will be the only developer for the project. It is not a big important project. 
I will just use commit,update and revert. I will NOT fork/clone/merge anything. 
At all times, my local repo will have the same file versions with the repo in BitBucket. 
It would be great if I just use eclipse and do not use terminal or BitBucket's web site.

Any help on the simplest use?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't willing to clone/push/fetch there is no point in trying to use git and bitbucket as almost all git operations require a local clone of the git repository you are working on. And in order to bring commits from your local clone to your repository on bitbucket you need to push them. Welcome to the distributed nature of git.

Comment: so? how to update? how to commit to repo? commit&push everytime? how to revert from repo?